# Windows 10: How to treat a bluetooth "Game Controller" as a Generic device?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I am trying to connect and develop for the Wii U pro controller.  On Windows 7 and Mac I can successfully connect the controller to Windows and use it through the Microsoft bluetooth stack.  However, on Windows 10 the HID device data becomes corrupted.

I think that this is because Windows is mistaking the Wii U Pro Controller for a generic bluetooth Game Controller (such as an XBox controller).  Is there a way I can force Windows to treat the Wii U pro controller as a generic bluetooth device instead of a gamepad?

Thanks,
Flafla2

Answer (score -2):

Go into the task manager set prioritey for the controller to high then adjust the treatment files to generic controlers in side a winrar zip file

Comment: hopw this helps

Comment: What are "treatment files"?